# How to import google cloud spanner data into local emulator environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, localhost, emulation, restore, google-cloud-spanner

I exported a spanner database on google cloud spanner UI page. Saved it to cloud storage. Also downloaded it to local environment.

I found a backup/restore guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup), it's for real cloud environment.

If import the data to spanner [emulator](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator), how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is currently not possible:

- The Spanner emulator will always start without any instances and databases.
- Any database that you create will always start out empty
- The emulator [does not support backup and restore operations](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-emulator/blob/master/README.md#features-and-limitations)
- Any data that you create while the emulator is running will be lost when it is shut down